# Diverting results with ajax in knockoutjs context

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I have this code (see below). Debugging and watching it with Firebug shows me I get the data I want inside the ".done"-function .My self.Task is exactly as I want it. However something is happening

```
ViewModel = function(serviceClient) {
...

serviceClient.getTasks(projectId)
        .done(function (data) {

            self.Tasks = ko.observableArray(
                ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function (item) {
                   return new TaskViewModel(item);
               }));

            alert("Inner result: " + self.Tasks().length + " task(s)");
        })

    alert("Outer result " + self.Tasks().length + " task(s)");

...
}
```

where

```
serviceClient.getTasks = function (param) {
        console.log("Get Model from Service");
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: serviceRoot + "GetAllTasks",
            beforeSend: serviceFramework.setModuleHeaders,
            data: "projectid=" + param,
            cache: false
        });
    };
```

Why are the INNER result and the OUTER result different?

Comment: Because the `a` in `ajax` means asynchronous.

Comment: Then how can I "wait" for the self.Tasks to "appear"?

I need the "data" from the ajax call (serviceClient.getTasks) outside the ".done"-function

Answer (score 0):

did you try success event in your ajax ? you can do all your array mapping inside this eventhandler

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that your ajax call isn't finishing before the "Outer" alert executes.  Consider doing something like:

```
var request = serviceClient.getTasks(projectID).done(function(data) {
  alert("Inner: " + data.length);
});
// ... more code ...
request.done(function(data) {
  alert("Outer: " + data.length);
});
```

Of course that seems kind of silly to me.  Feels like the 2nd alert should just be in the first `.done` handler.  This is the equivalent of:

```
serviceClient.getTasks(...).done(function(data) {
  alert("Inner");
  alert("Outer");
});
```

No good: http://jsfiddle.net/bqsjm/

One solution: http://jsfiddle.net/bqsjm/1/

You'll either need to elegantly pass around the ajax's returned promise object or add function calls inside of the `.done` function that executes after you set `self.Tasks`

Speaking of which, you're orphaning `self.Tasks` from the DOM when you write:

```
self.Tasks = ko.observableArray(...arrayMap...);
```

I think you meant to write:

```
self.Tasks(...arrayMap...);
```

Consider:

```
// DOM
<span data-bind="text: $root.foo"></span>

// Javascript land
var vm = { foo: ko.observable("foo") };
ko.applyBindings(vm);
// <span> tag will read "foo"
vm.foo = ko.observable("bar");// orphaned
// <span> tag still reads "foo"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: In my viewmodel the following works perfectly:


    ViewModel = function (model, serviceClient) {
    var self = this;

    self.Projects = ko.observableArray(
        ko.utils.arrayMap(model, function (item) {
            return new ProjectViewModel(item);
        }));

...

Comment: This is how the viewmodel is called:

var client = new ServiceClient(<%=ModuleId %>);
        client.getModel(<%=ModuleId %>)
            .done(function (model) {
                var viewModel = new ViewModel(model, client);
                ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById("<%= ClientID %>"));
            })

Comment: Calling "serviceClient.getTasks" returns "data".
I am able to catch the data INSIDE the ".done"-function, but somehow it is undefined outside.